# Play 2.5 akka.actor.ActorSystem isTerminated method deprecated

Tags: java, akka, playframework-2.5

I'm upgrading my project to Play 2.5. In the previous version I used the following code to schedule task via Akka:

```
private ActorSystem actorSystem = Play.current().injector().instanceOf(ActorSystem.class);

    private void scheduleUpdate() {
        if (actorSystem.isTerminated()) {
            return;
        }
        //run schedule code
    }
```

But isTerminated method (returning boolean) is deprecated now and I'm encouraged to use whenTerminated instead. However, I'm not sure how to properly refactor this code here, since whenTerminated seems to have completely different functionality. If someone gives me an advice about this - it would be quite helpful.

Answer (score 1):

`ActorSystem.whenTerminated` returns a `Future<Terminated>` which is a Scala datastructure much like `CompletableFuture` which was added in Java 8. You can query if it is completed through the method `.isCompleted()` to mimic your old logic.